# Issue returning function in AngularJS Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

Here is my service:

```
web.factory('distance', function() {
    Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
        return this * Math.PI / 180;
    };

    return function(origin, destination) {
        var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
        var dLat = (origin.lat()-destination.lat()).toRad();  // Javascript functions in radians
        var dLon = (origin.lng()-destination.lng()).toRad();
        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(origin.lat().toRad()) * Math.cos(destination.lat().toRad()) *
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        return R * c; // Distance in km
    };
});
```

Returning the function in my distance service is bombing out.  Apparently it cannot see the method called origin.lat().  I thought in javascript you didn't have to initialize anything as a type prior?

Here is the error i am getting in chrome at the first occurence of `"origin.lat()":`

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Any help appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code where you are calling this factory

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: Edited it.  Let me know if that looks better.  The issue i have is a javascript functionality issue (how to use), I tried to reflect htat in the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is that lat is not identified as a function on 'origin'.

Now your factory should return an object that contains a function and not a function.

You will perform your call to that function after injecting the function to whereever you want.

```
web.factory('distance', function() {

    // Should this be here???
    Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
        return this * Math.PI / 180;
    };

    return
        {
          calculate:function(origin, destination) {
                 var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
                 var dLat = (origin.lat()-destination.lat()).toRad();  // Javascript functions in radians
                 var dLon = (origin.lng()-destination.lng()).toRad();
                 var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                 Math.cos(origin.lat().toRad()) * Math.cos(destination.lat().toRad()) *
                 Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
                 var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
                 return R * c; // Distance in km
        }
    };
});
```

You should use: `distance.calculate(a,b)` where you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I got what you have above implemented and now i get a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( "     at the line
--  calculate:function(origin, destination) {  ---

Webstorm is highlighting the first parentheses right here "function(origin" and is saying a function name is expected??
I am a js / angular newb so thanks for any help and the help you have already given.

Comment: I've created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4nHfa/

Comment: Just saw, the fiddle, will copy that and see what i get.  Thanks again.  Going to accept this cause the fiddle works, so must be something else on my side.

Comment: why are lat\lng functions? they should be properties on your object.

Comment: i am using the google.maps.LatLng class.  So i am passing that object and calling it's prebuilt functions.

Comment: weird thing, i see your fiddle working with that toRad function in there.  however for me to get it to work I had to inject it as a service into my service.  Not a big deal, but a little odd (these are the things that drive me batty about programming).

Thanks again!

Comment: toRad shouldn't sit inside a factory\service. Typically what you are doing here is adding a function to the Number object's prototype. Now this should occur once in a seperate js file that loads before you application loads.